# Jquery.DataTables dynamically add new record to already existing dataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

Any kind help would be greatly appreciated:

Message "Requested unknown parameter 'Check' for row 201" when dynamically adding new row to an exsisting table.

I am trying to dynamically add new records to an already created DataTable. ( After the user click on a certain button, the program determines how many records it has to add and add them on the fly. Here is how I initialize the DataTable:

```
_tbl_actv = $(table).DataTable({
        "scrollY": '450px',
        "bAutoWidth": true,
        //"scrollCollapse": true,
        "bFilter": true,
        "bLengthChange": true,
        "info": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 25,
        data: collection,
        columns: [
            { data: 'Check', width: "5%" },
            { data: 'Descr_En' }
        ],
        "columnDefs": [                
            { "title": "#", "targets": 0 },
            { "title": "Activity", "targets": 1 }
        ]
    });
```

Initially 'collection' contains 200 rows. Later on the user may add several new rows with a single action. And here is how these records are dynamically added.

_tbl_actv.row.add([{ Check: row.Check, 
                     Descr_En: row.Descr_En }]);

--> **error message thrown!**

_tbl_actv.draw();

Delving into the source code of Jquery.DataTables js, I see these:

1. Initially when DataTable loads for the first time the first 200 records, the function "_fnGetObjectDataFn" is called and returns a pointer to a function to further access this **particular row** later on. In my case it is the pointer (copy paste from source code):

   /* Array or flat object mapping */

   ```
       return function (data, type) { // row and meta also passed, but not used

           return data[mSource];

       };
   ```

   which is the last case

   After this call, all the 200 rows are **individually** pointed by access function (for speedup reason).
2. For the new record, the 201rst record this call fails because I see the 'mSource' variable is undefined for this new row although I can see that 'data' (which is an array) contains my new record. Thus the call fails because it returns nothing (undefined). It looks like in order to dynamically add a row into DataTable there must be some kind of reset so that 'access function' can be built for these new records (and thus 'mSource' will have a valid value for new record). Is there a more suitable call to add a row to the DataTable? Is this a bug ( i am using version **1.10.2** ), or more likely have I missed something very important?

Thank you very much for your time, your insight is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add rows as objects in array either you have to add rows as an array or an object see [docs](http://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()), if you want to add multiple rows that would be done with arrays in arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what was supposed to be done. It is working now.